# Why is setting state on array not working?

Tags: react-native, state

I am trying to make a system where you would pass in a bunch of coins and they would get added to the state array (selectedTickers). Once I would set selectedTickers to another array, it would still print out the original array. Anyone know how to get this to print out the new array?

Code:

```
function addTickerToList(ticker) {
    const exists = selectedTickers.filter((a) => a === ticker);
    console.log(exists);

    if (exists.length > 0) {
      console.log("first");
      let newList = selectedTickers.filter((a) => a !== ticker);
      setSelectedTickers(newList);
      console.log(selectedTickers);
    } else {
      console.log("second");
      console.log(ticker);

      selectedTickers.push(ticker);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you show the full code

Answer (score 0):

setSelectedTickers is asynchronous.

You are logging selectedTickers before the function fully executed, try to log it on the web page to ensure that the re-render is done.